# Excel negative number formatting and scaling

Tags: formatting, excel-2013

how can I display -1,000,000 as (1,000) in Excel? I have tried #,##0, but it cannot add () at front and end. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks you!

Comment: You need to pick the "Accounting" formats

Answer (score 0):

About negative formatting:

> A number format can have up to four sections of code, separated by
>   semicolons. These code sections define the format for positive
>   numbers, negative numbers, zero values, and text, in that order.
>
> POSITIVE;NEGATIVE;ZERO;TEXT

To add the parentheses

> To display both text and numbers in a cell, enclose the text
>   characters in double quotation marks (" ")

Final format

```
"("#.##0")";"("#.##0")"
```

Since the Negative formatting don't have a fixed character before the numer (like -), it will displayer the number without it.

[Full Documentation](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Create-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4?ui=en-US&rs=en-ZA&ad=ZA)

Answer (score 0):

To scale down a number you need to create a custom format and put a comma at the end of each of the positive and negative digit formatting. This custom format

```
#,##0,;(#,##0,)
```

will display `1000000` as `1,000` and `-1000000` as `(1,000)`.

The comma at the end will scale the number down by a thousand (10^3). You can add extra commas if you want to scale further. 2 commas `#,##0,,;(#,##0,,)` will scale down by a million (10^6) and 3 commas `#,##0,,,;(#,##0,,,)` will scale by a billion (10^9) and so on.